# How to add Image + Text in button Value onClick?

Tags: javascript

I have a button and on click on it the text changes and I want to include Image with it and don't know how, I'm new with JavaScript, help please!

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" id="pay-btn" value="Click here to check" />
```

```
function change()
{
  document.getElementById("pay-btn").value="'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOnzy.gif' please wait...";
}
```

I tried to search on StackOverflow and Google but don't find a way to do this.

Comment: Well, first one, you should use <button><img /></button> instead of input button. But if you want, you shoud add class="img1" and change the class after click to img2 by CSS styles.

Comment: Hi @daremachine could you please write me an example based on the code I've shared on m question so I could understand better, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

As requested, an example using `addEventListener`. The main differences are that the JavaScript logic stays within the JavaScript files. Besides that, you can only add one `onclick` listener, but multiple listeners with `addEventListener`.

Next to that it shows an example of how to create an image within JavaScript, add a `src` and `alt` to it, before appending it to the button. If you'd inspect the button with your browser tools, you'll see that the HTML has changed.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const span = button.querySelector('span');

// Listen for all clicks on the button.
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // Create a new image.
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOnzy.gif';
  image.alt = 'Loading';
  
  // Append the image to the button.
  button.append(image);
  
  // Change the text inside of the span.
  span.textContent = 'Now I am changed';
});
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 6px;
}

button img {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>Not changed</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" height=20></button>
```

the data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs= is an empty image and you can change it with the opposite image of loading

**and js**

```
<script>
  function myFunction(e) {
    e.querySelector('button img').src= "https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOnzy.gif";
  }
</script>
```

**The scenario is:**

1. button is paired html tag and gives you better maintain body of    button
2. myFunction(this) pass the current element like e into your function
3. e.querySelector('button img') is, find button and img inside of current html element
4. set img src to my image path

**EDIT**

you can do it by same way

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" height=20>
  <div>what?</div>
</button>
```

add this line into your function

```
e.querySelector('button div').innerText = "hello my text has changed";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it! But now I'm struggling that how I can add the text " please wait... " next to image?

Comment: I have updated my answer, but I strongly suggest you to read any tutorials, for example https://www.w3schools.com/ it is good start for you. Happy coding

Comment: Please stimulate the usage of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of [inline event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). The latter is an outdated technique and can be confusing, as your example demonstrates with the `this` value being passed.

Comment: @daremachine unfortunately this code not working either :(

Comment: @EmielZuurbier could you help me with the newest technique? Thank you guys in advance for help

Comment: yes it is but I wanted only help modify OP code, not teach him other things. I strongly suggest him to learn and read some tutorials about that problem. You are right ofc.